# What does William James mean here by representing the knowing in advance?

Tags: reality, william-james

> Let my reader suppose himself to constitute for a time all the reality
> there is in the universe, and then to receive the announcement that
> another being is to be created who shall know him truly. **How will he
> represent the knowing in advance?**

(Mind, New Series, Vol. 13, No. 52 (Oct., 1904), p. 467)

**My questions:**

1. If the reader constitutes all the reality there is in the universe, then how can he receive an announcement from an external source? If only the reader exists, then there cannot be anything outside him that exists. Then where did the announcement come from?
2. What does James mean by the emphasized sentence?

---

I am adding more material here for context:

> This is surely enough to show that the humanist does not ignore the
> character of objectivity and independence in truth. Let me turn next
> to what his opponents mean when they say that to be true, our
> thoughts must 'correspond'. The vulgar notion of correspondence here
> is that the thoughts must copy the reality-cognitio fit per
> assimiliationem cogniti et cognoscentis; and philosophy, without
> having ever fairly sat down to the question, seems to have;
> instinctively accepted this idea: propositions are held true if they
> copy the eternal thought; terms are held true if they copy
> extra-mental realities. Implicitly, I think that  the copy-theory has
> animated most of the criticisms that have been made on humanism. A
> priori, however, it is not self-evident that the sole business of
> our mind with realities should be to copy them. **Let  my reader suppose
> himself to constitute for a time all the  reality there is in the
> universe, and then to receive the announcement that another being is
> to be created who shall know him truly. How will he represent the
> knowing in advance?** What will he hope it to be? I doubt extremely
> whether it could ever occur to him to fancy it as a mere  copying. Of
> what use to him would an imperfect second edition of himself in the
> newcomer's interior be? It would  seem pure waste of a propitious
> opportunity. The demand  would more probably be for something
> absolutely new. The reader would conceive the knowing humanistically,
> "the  new comer," he would say, "must take account of my presence
> by reacting on it in such a way that good would accrue to us both.
> If copying be requisite to that end, let there be copying; otherwise
> not." The essence in any case would not be the  copying, but the
> enrichment of the previous world.

**Bonus question:**

"Of what use to him would an **imperfect** second edition of himself in the newcomer's interior be?" I wonder why James used the word imperfect here. Is he implying that knowing someone truly is impossible?

Comment: Compare with the much earlier [“Remarks on Spencer’s Definition of Mind as Correspondence” (1878)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/james/#RemaSpenDefiMindCorr1878): the mind is not designed to "reflect" reality: “there belongs to mind, from its birth upward, a spontaneity, a vote. It is in the game, and not a mere looker-on; and its judgments of the should-be, its ideals, cannot be peeled off from the body of the cogitandum as if they were excrescences…”

Comment: The thought experiment is aimed at showing that the idea that "knowing" is "copying an external reality" is untenable: "A priori, however, it is not self-evident that the sole business of our mind with realities should be to copy them. " The newly created being "is to be created who shall know him [the reader] truly"; but if this situation is possible (is it?) how would the newcomer know the reader **before** encountering him?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "how would the newcomer know the reader before encountering him?" According to my understanding, James thinks that an adherent of the copy-theory will say that as the newcomer must know the reader truly and as knowledge takes place through the assimilation of the known and the knower, the newcomer must have a copy of the essence of the reader in his interior.

Comment: "Of what use to him would an **imperfect** second edition of himself in the newcomer's interior be?" I wonder why James used the word imperfect here. Is he implying that knowing someone truly is impossible?

Comment: *Imperfect* here means he's subsumed and entirely copied in another being. The announcement may come from another universe from the multiverses or metaverse. If you attend to his later part of your quoted section it's apparent that *represent* here means conceive of and pragmatic hope from such knowing in advance...